# Possible stack overflow when using lamba function?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, recursion

In the example given by http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp, we can see such chunk of code:

```
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
```

I am pretty new to C++11. So I was wondering wether this code would lead to stack overflow (too much recursive calls) or not, since do_accept() kind of registers a callback of do_accept().

Thanks.

Comment: `do_accept` never calls itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. `async_accept` is going to fire off an asynchronous call and return right away -- `do_accept` therefore returns right after calling it.

Later on, the asynchronous call will finish, and `do_accept` will be called to fire off another asynchronous call. No recursion is involved.